# How to change QListWidget setText position to top?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I am trying to change my QListWidget text title in different position, from right side of the picture to the top:

now it looks like:

[image]

I want something looks like this:

[image]

my code:

video_thumbnail.setFlow(QListView.LeftToRight)

```
for i in range(30):
    it = QListWidgetItem()
    it.setIcon(QIcon('test3.png'))
    it.setText(str(i))
    video_thumbnail.addItem(it)
video_thumbnail.setIconSize(QSize(128, 128))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a delegate to modify the position of the icon and the text:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QListView,
    QListWidget,
    QListWidgetItem,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
    QStyleOptionViewItem,
)


class StyledItemDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignCenter
        option.decorationPosition = QStyleOptionViewItem.Bottom


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    video_thumbnail = QListWidget(flow=QListView.LeftToRight)
    video_thumbnail.setIconSize(QSize(128, 128))
    delegate = StyledItemDelegate(video_thumbnail)
    video_thumbnail.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    for i in range(30):
        it = QListWidgetItem()
        it.setIcon(QIcon("test3.png"))
        it.setText(str(i))
        video_thumbnail.addItem(it)
    video_thumbnail.resize(400, 100)
    video_thumbnail.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, but why the image couldn't load? :(

Comment: @Nikki I am using the code that you provide and I have not modified the code that loads the QIcon, try using the fullpath of the .png